# What can I do to have more energy/less sleepy before working out?

Tags: sleep, energy

I wake up at 7am, go to college, after go to work, and at the end of the day - when I am as sleepy as 30 bears - I go to the gym.

After returning from gym, I dinner, etc and sleep

What can I do to reduce my sleepiness? Caffeine? Energy drinks?

Please no capsules or powders (supplements) like ASSAULT or Jack3d ! I already take creatine and whey protein.

Also I think something isn't right with my sleep, because I wake more tired than when I went to sleep, it's awkward and bothers a lot, I just can't wake up, I'm a "zombie" the first 5 minutes after waking (When I don't back to sleep after waking)

Comment: If you can, try and get up early and the morning and workout **before** going to school.  Then you'll have all of the energy to get your workout done and won't be too tired to complete your workout.  I've heard other benefits for doing it int he morning but I don't know those off the top of my head, so I'm making this as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notably lacking from your question is the amount of sleep you get. I am going to assume you are getting at least 8 hours of actual sleep (remember to include the time it takes for you to actually drift off). If you aren't getting a full 8 hours of sleep, well then my answer should be pretty obvious: **get more sleep**.

The best compilation of advice I've found on this topic has been [LifeHacker's High Energy Workday Guide](http://lifehacker.com/5664322/eat-your-way-to-a-high-energy-workday). The advice is all sound, and has worked well for me. I suggest reading the entire article, but let me summarize the key points:

1. **Breakfast > Lunch > Dinner**. Breakfast and lunch are the foundation that feed your energy throughout the day, so treat them with respect and make them hearty meals.
2. **Regulate blood sugar**. Be mindful of the amount of carbs you eat and the glucose index of your foods. You want to prevent the high/low blood sugar swings that result in energy crashes, and instead have a more regular level of blood sugar. This is most easily accomplished by sticking to [low glycemic index foods](http://www.glycemicindex.com/).
3. **Eat frequently**. Don't do three big meals a day and starve yourself in between. You should have a small snack between meals, which usually comes out to eating every 2-3 hours. This helps with #2 regulating blood sugar, just make sure to stick to low glycemic snacks or snacks with high protein count.
4. **Stay hydrated**. Water plays an instrumental role in keeping your energy level up. Get a Nalgene bottle or something similar, and take it with you to school/work/etc..
5. **Still having problems?** If you are still having problems maintaining your energy level, then you should start keeping a log and see if you can notice any patterns. It may be as simple as changing your eating habits by 30 minutes. Alternatively, after a long day you could just be exhausted and stressed out, at which point your best bet is restructuring your daily routine so you get up earlier to hit the gym in the morning.

Comment: You're right, my sleep doesn't last for 8 hours, I'll start sleeping earlier; Also I don't breakfast everyday, I wake up late and need to leave house as fast as possible... Thanks for the tips, about the eating frequency, the only meal I don't do is the breakfast, the rest of the day I eat regularly. Thanks again